# Android maps route not found message

Tags: android, google-maps, android-mapview

I just want to draw a direction from current location to such a location. When I start map activity ı just have this warning in map view.

"No route found"

My code is below. source and destionation are like => "23.45, 34.112". What is he reason of his warning? Is Uri not correct?

```
Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
            Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=" + source + "&daddr="+destination));
    this.context.startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Have you tried searching [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/coverage) if the location you are looking for has a Google Map coverage? Also what [Travel Mode](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro#TravelModes) did you use?